# How do i count the number of similar values in a column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
    #   Name    Type 1  Type 2  Total   HP  Attack  Defense  
1   Bulbasaur   Grass   Poison  318     45  49      65      
2   Ivysaur     Grass   Poison  405     60  62      80      
3   Venusaur    Grass   Poison  525     80  82      100     
4   Charmander  Fire    NaN     309     39  52      60      
5   Charmeleon  Fire    NaN     405     58  64      80
```

I have a dataframe like the above. I need to calculate the number of 'Grass' type pokemons from 'Type 1'.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df['Type 1'].value_counts()
print (df)
Grass    3
Fire     2
Name: Type 1, dtype: int64
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Type 1']).size()
print (df)
Type 1
Fire     2
Grass    3
dtype: int64
```